# How to append to a CakePHP3 ResultSet?

Tags: cakephp, iterator, cakephp-3.0

I have a query (a Query object):

```
$joblineitems = $this->JobLineItems->find('all');
```

It has results (a ResultSet object):

```
$joblineitemsresults = $joblineitems->all();
```

The ResultSet object is an Iterable such that a foreach() loop will return each of the JobLineItem objects.

I simply want to add an additional result to $joblineitemsresults - specifically I want to append a $this->JobLineItems->newEntity() to the end of the results so that when I subsequently paginate $joblineitemsresults and loop through it in the view, the last object in the loop on the last page will be a blank object with the property new=true.

How can I manually append an extra result to a ResultSet object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
$joblineitems = $this->JobLineItems->find('all');
$joblineitemsresults = $joblineitems->all();

$joblineitemsresults = $joblineitemsresults ->append([$this->JobLineItems->newEntity()]);
debug($joblineitemsresults ->toList());
```

You can see the [manual](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/collections.html#expanding-collections) for reference

pay attention in particular to the last paragraph

> When appending from different sources, you can expect some keys from
> both collections to be the same. For example, when appending two
> simple arrays. This can present a problem when converting a collection
> to an array using toArray(). If you do not want values from one
> collection to override others in the previous one based on their key,
> make sure that you call toList() in order to drop the keys and
> preserve all values.

That's why I used `toList()` instead of `toArray()`. If you use `toArray()` you'll see the new entity override the first one.

Of course you can also transform your recordset in an array and then append the new entity to the array

```
$joblineitemsresults = $joblineitems->toArray();
joblineitemsresults[] = $this->JobLineItems->newEntity();
```

Comment: I marked it as correct because it does what I asked - but I have since discovered that I can't use Paginator on the $joblineitemsresults, it has to be on the QUERY itself $joblineitems.

Do you know if I can append a newEntity to the bottom of the query results WITHIN the query $joblineitems so that the newEntity can be paginated?

Comment: I think you'll have to create a custom paginator in order to obtain this. But maybe you can trick the paginator: modify your query so it find a record more (i.e. using a union) then after the pagination replace that record with a new entity. It's not a very clean approach, I know

Comment: Thanks for that, I agree it's quickly getting out of hand. Suddenly I'm envious of the Cake 2 days when a find returned an array, instead of objects with protected properties and no public methods to change the contents of said protected properties.