# add field to query in cakephp3

Tags: php, cakephp

In cakephp3 I cant seem to add a field to a query result.In cakephp2 this idea was easy but since I am dealing with objects this is different. I checked previous SE posts and couldnt get the answer. It must be simple but  I cant find it.
 Here I am trying to add a custom field  'distance' to a result set

```
$lessons=$this->Lessons->getLessonsDay($searchDate,$searchFirstName,$searchLastName,$searchSubject, $tutorIds);
         foreach( $lessons as $key => $item){
        //  debug($item); 
             $stlat=$item->student->address_lat;
             $stlong=$item->student->address_long;
             $tutlat=$item->tutor->address_lat;
             $tutlong=$item->tutor->address_long; 

              $dist=$this->calculate_distance( $stlat,$stlong,$tutlat,$tutlong);
              debug($dist);
             $lessons->distance= $dist; //no effect
             $lessons[$key]['distance']=$dist; //error
             $lessons[$key]['Lessons']['distance']=$dist; //Error: Cannot use object of type Cake\ORM\Query as array  

            }
```

[How to append to a CakePHP3 ResultSet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37336540/how-to-append-to-a-cakephp3-resultset)

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#checking-if-a-query-or-resultset-is-empty

Comment: maybe you want to do `$item->distance = $dist`

Comment: ok can you set this as the  answer

Comment: I don't think this will come useful for someone else

Answer (score -1, accepted):

maybe you want to do

```
$item->distance = $dist – arilia
```

Comment: This worked so if there is a problem could the person who voted this down explain and give a better answer. It isnt really helpful just marking the post down without explanantion